# Sum the number of children with vfork()

Tags: c, bash, ubuntu

I want to write a program with vfork() and parent creates n children, I want to insert number of sons with parameter. And then I want to sum the number of sons for example:

```
./sum 4
The sum of the child: 10
The sum of the parent: 10
```

(1+2+3+4)

This is the small code I came up, but I get infinite loop.

```
int n = atoi(argv[1]);
int i = 1;
pid_t pid;
int sumchild = 0;
int sumparent = 0;

    while(i <= n){
        pid = vfork();
        if(pid == 0){
            sumchild = sumchild + i;        
        }

        i++;
    }
    printf("The sum of the child: %i ", sumchild);

    sumparent = (1 + n) * (n / 2);
    printf("The sum of the parent: %i \n", sumparent);
```

I heard that you don't need `wait()` like in `fork()`, but I don't know why do I get infinite loop here.

How should I use `vfork()`?
Did I even write the code right or I made some mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

The following code

```
    pid = vfork();
    if(pid == 0){
        sumchild = sumchild + i;
```

will cause undefined behavior, according to [`vfork`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/vfork):

> The vfork() function has the same effect as fork(2), except that the behavior is undefined if the process created by vfork() either modifies any data other than a variable of type pid_t used to store the return value from vfork(), or returns from the function in which vfork() was called, or calls any other function before successfully calling _exit(2) or one of the exec(3) family of functions.